# Node.js loading Postgres SQL data into JS FIle

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

I'm attempting to load the Postgres data into node.js and I'm having a lot of difficulty with it. I know the constring works because I used it to send the data from the a textfile into the database.

```
var request = require('request');
var pg = require('pg');
var squel=require('squel');
var client = new pg.Client(conString);
var conString="postgres://postgres:Password@localhost:5433/postgres"

client.connect(function (err,data){
    if(err) console.log("Error connecting to PG", err);
    else{
    var query = squel.select().from('"ASNTable"')
    console.log(query.toString());
    client.query(query, function(res){
              var outputJSON = [];
              for (row in res){
                outputJSON.push(row);
              }
              return outputJSON
              console.log(outputJSON)
            });
    }
});
```

I keep getting "SELECT * FROM "ASNTable" so its like the client.query part never does anything?

Comment: did you change the default postgres port to 5433? it's 5432 unless you changed it.

Comment: @aembke Yeah I did actually. I've successfully entered data from node to the database but I can't seem to reverse it.

Comment: A couple things: you don't need to double quote the table name string. Also, the first parameter in the callback function to client.query() is an error, not the response. You should change that line to client.query(query, function(error, res){ ... }). Also, you should check out the node-postgres documentation. The for(row in res) won't work how you'd like. You want the res.rows property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@aembke I figured it out.
The var conString should go before client.

```
var request = require('request');
var pg = require('pg');
var squel=require('squel');
var conString="postgres://postgres:Vcu3student@localhost:5433/postgres"
var client = new pg.Client(conString);
var outputJSON = [];

client.connect(function (err,data){
    if(err) console.log("'Error connecting to PG'", err);
    else{
    var query = squel.select().field("asnumber").from('"asntable"');
    client.query(query.toString(), function (err,res){
        if (err) throw err;
        var x = JSON.stringify(res);
        var y = x.split(",")
        // console.log(y[7])
        console.log(y.length);
        for (var i=0; i<y.length; i++){
            // console.log(y[i]);
            if (y[i].indexOf('"asnumber":') > 0)
            {
                console.log(y[i])
                outputJSON.push(y[i]);
            }
        };
        // console.log("result "+JSON.stringify(res))
          });
    }
});
console.log(outputJSON);
```